Trying to start a meeting using Microsoft Teams
I'm trying to start a Microsoft Teams meeting from my Flutter application using the url_launcher package. I have a base URL set and a text field where the user enters the meeting ID. However, when I try to launch the meeting on my phone, it doesn't seem to do anything.
Here is the code I have so far:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TeamsIntegrationScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TeamsIntegrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeamsIntegrationScreenState createState() => _TeamsIntegrationScreenState();
}

class _TeamsIntegrationScreenState extends State<TeamsIntegrationScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _meetingUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final String _baseTeamsUrl = 'https://teams.live.com/meet/9532579737749?p=';

  Future<void> _launchTeams() async {
    String meetingUrl = _baseTeamsUrl + _meetingUrlController.text;
    print('Launching URL: $meetingUrl');  // For debugging

    if (meetingUrl.isNotEmpty) {
      try {
        bool canLaunchUrl = await canLaunch(meetingUrl);
        if (canLaunchUrl) {
          await launch(meetingUrl);
        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Could not launch $meetingUrl')),
          );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('An error occurred: $e')),
        );
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Please enter a meeting URL.')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Start Microsoft Teams Meeting'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _meetingUrlController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Meeting ID',
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _launchTeams,
              child: Text('Join Teams Meeting'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
Issue:

When I enter a meeting ID and press the "Join Teams Meeting" button, nothing happens. The URL does not launch, and no error messages are shown. The URL scheme is https://teams.live.com/meet/9532579737749?p= followed by the user-provided meeting ID.


I just tried your code, and it is giving me proper error SnackBar. What exactly is the problem? Is it not giving any snackbar message also for you? If that is the case, try adding more logs or use debugger. And please share the logs here.

The problem is its not opening the url to start the teams meeting. so i dont know what the problem could be

Then it could be the problem with configuration. Have you added  for android for https scheme? https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#configuration
